# how to center content inside a card- bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have a card in my UI but i cant figure out on how to center the content inside it

```
  <div class="col-sm-4 pb-3">
      <!-- Card -->
<div class="card card-image" style="background-color:grey;">

  <!-- Content -->
  <div class="text-white text-center d-flex align-items-center rgba-black-strong py-5 px-4">
    <div>
      <h5 class="pink-text"><i class="fas fa-chart-pie"></i>Your Rewards</h5>
      <h3 class="card-title pt-2"><strong>Earned AGI</strong></h3>
      <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-6">
        <h3>Option 1</h3>
        <p>SNET</p>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block px-1" id="reinvest">REINVEST</button>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-6">
        <h3>Option 2</h3>
        <p>AGI</p>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block px-1 " id="withdraw">WITHDRAW</button>
      </div>
    </div>

    </div>
  </div>

</div>
<!-- Card -->
    </div>
  </div>
```

The problem seem to be the buttons which dont stay inside the card on a ipad and ipad pro

You can view the UI im talking about here
obedient-pan.surge.sh

The problem i have is with the "your rewards" card on the right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a  `d-flex` class in this line:
`<div class="text-white text-center d-flex align-items-center rgba-black-strong py-5 px-4">`.

It would add the attribute `display: flexbox;`  to your div element.

You can add a `justify-content-center` class in it, to make it center the content in a flexbox way.

Moreover, if you don't need it to act like a flexbox at all, feel free to remote the `d-flex` class.

Check the [#justify-content part of bootstrap docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/utilities/flex/#justify-content)

```html
 <div class="col-sm-4 pb-3">
      <!-- Card -->
<div class="card card-image" style="background-color:grey;">

  <!-- Content -->
  <div class="text-white text-center d-flex align-items-center rgba-black-strong py-5 px-4 justify-content-center">
    <div>
      <h5 class="pink-text"><i class="fas fa-chart-pie"></i>Your Rewards</h5>
      <h3 class="card-title pt-2"><strong>Earned AGI</strong></h3>
      <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-6">
        <h3>Option 1</h3>
        <p>SNET</p>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block px-1" id="reinvest">REINVEST</button>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-6">
        <h3>Option 2</h3>
        <p>AGI</p>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block px-1 " id="withdraw">WITHDRAW</button>
      </div>
    </div>

    </div>
  </div>

</div>
<!-- Card -->
    </div>
  </div>
  
  
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Just add this css into your css File, it will automatically center the content.

Css::Align-horizontal center

 .text-center {
    display:flex;
    justify-content:center;
    }
```

Css::Align-vertically+horizontal center

```
 .text-center {
    display:flex;
    justify-content:center;
    align-items: center;
    }
```